# Biconditional Statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Upon reading my textbook it gives a definition for a biconditional statement as the following:

> Given statement variables $p$ and $q$, the **biconditional of $p$ and $q$** is "$p$ if, and only if, $q$ and is denoted $p \leftrightarrow q$.

It then mentions that:

> It is true if both $p$ and $q$ have the same truth values and is false if $p$ and $q$ have opposite truth values. The words...

My question is, from the second part of the definition, is it talking about if $p$ is equal to *true* and $q$ is equal to *true* then the outcome will be *true*? Likewise if both are *false*, the outcome will be *true*? Also, if that is the case, is it saying that the rest, i.e. $p$ being *true* or *false* and $q$ being its opposite, the outcome will always be *false*?

Comment: If what you mean by _outcome_ is the truth value of $p\leftrightarrow q$, then yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation is correct.  Here is the truth table for the biconditional:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
p & q & p\iff q \\\hline
T & T & T\\\hline
T & F & F \\\hline
F & T & F \\\hline
F & F & T
\end{array}$$

Comment: Hm.  Par answered ~40s ahead of me.  I don't want to lose the work for the table, so I'll just leave my answer here. `;)`

Comment: If I could I would give everyone the credit for answering, but I liked how the table was set. Thanks for confirming my hypothesis! ha! no math pun intended.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. See the following truth table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The biconditional "p if and only if q" can be read as "p implies q AND q implies p". In this way analyzing a biconditional reduces to analyzing two implications.